# Link in typed.js text

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, effect, typed

How do i put link in `typed.js` script? I need Contact me, to be linked to contact page.

```
    <script src="js/typed.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function(){
          $(".element").typed({
            strings: ["Welcome to my Website.", "Random text... Contact me"],
            typeSpeed: 0
          });
      });
    </script>

 **HTML**

<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
    <h1 class="element"></h1>
 </div>
```

Comment: You should load jQuery _before_ it's plugins.

Comment: I have it link this.. `code`<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/typed.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function(){
      $(".element").typed({
        strings: ["Welcome to my Website.", "Random text,  Contact me."],
        typeSpeed: 0
      });
  });
</script>`code`

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I need Contact me, to be a link,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the callback parameter.

#### Example:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#awesome').typed({
    strings: ["Welcome to my Website.", "Random text... Contact me"],
    typeSpeed: 0,
    callback: function() {
      $('#awesome').html('<a href="#">' + $('#awesome').html() + '</a>')
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mattboldt/typed.js/master/js/typed.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
  <h1 class="element" id="awesome"></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks ;) It's working but now everything in <h1 class="element"></h1> is linked.

Comment: @KristjanVričko Please edit your question and provide your HTML code...It's a matter of CSS selectors.

Comment: I suggest you identify the text placeholder with an id

Comment: @NabilKadimi I think you have missed the actual question here. By using the callback func. the text inside `#awesome` always will be anchored. But the question to only anchor the `Contact me` text in the `typed.js`. This is a very good question. But I'm sorry that the answer you gave doesn't fit the question.